Decomposing the identity as sum of products of Bernoulli random variables
Suppose that $X_i$ is a sequence of i.i.d Bernoulli random variables such that $\mathbb{P}[X_i = 1] = p$.
Now, among the first $n$ variables concentration of measure tells us that it is very likely that close to $pn$ are 1. In particular, one can prove that probability that fewer than $\frac{pn}{2}$ of the variables is 1 tends to zero as $n \to \infty$.
Now for the some subsets $S \subset \{1, ,n\}$ with more than $\frac{pn}{2}$  elements I'd like to construct a random variable $X \approx 1$ on the form
$$X = \sum_{S \subset \{1, ,n\}} c_S 1[ X_i=1, \forall i \in S], $$
with $c_S = 0$ if $\vert S \vert \leq \frac{pn}{2}$.
It is easy to "fine tune" c_S such that $\mathbb{E}(X) = 1$. But is there a clever choice of coefficients such that
$$
E[(X-1)^2] \to 0 
$$
as $n \to \infty$?
My progress:
If I let  $\{X_i=1, \forall i \in S\} = \mathcal{E}_S$, then
I can write
$$ 
E[(X-1)^2] = E[X^2]-1 = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = \sum_{S,S'} c_Sc_S'(\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{E}_S, \mathcal{E}_{S'}]- \mathbb{P}[\mathcal{E}_S] \mathbb{P}[ \mathcal{E}_{S'}])
$$
Now, in the special case where I for $K$ nonzero coefficients set $c_S = \frac{1}{ K \mathbb{P}[\mathcal{E}_S]}$, I get
$$
\frac{1}{K^2} \sum_{S,S'}\left(\frac{\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{E}_S, \mathcal{E}_{S'}]}{\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{E}_S] \mathbb{P}[ \mathcal{E}_{S'}]}\right) -1. 
$$
In that case I need that the usual overlap between the sets $S$ and $S'$ is small. If I just pick all of the sets around the size of $\frac{pn}{2}$ then the usual overlap would be $(\frac{pn}{2})^2$ and so the term should be around $p^{- (\frac{pn}{2})^2} -1 $ which does not tend to $0$, but to $\infty$. So what is a smarter choice of coefficients? And what could be useful references and keywords?
